# How to force Flyway to show SQL error message instead of default SQL state :99999 code:17110

Tags: flyway

I have set `flyway.errorOverride=99999:17110:E` in the flyway.conf file But still don't see the actual SQL error instead I am getting the same `(SQL state: 99999, code: 17110)`.

I am using the Flyway Runner plugin in Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this setting into config file of flyway on the server side.
But you have to know this option is available only in teams (non-free) editions.